# What does data-... in a a tag or div tag do

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking at some apis and plugins and I've been seeing plugins that look like this

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

or

```
<a class="bistri-button" data-key="871b7d8f839e9cdbfc6dcc87b6932889feae334d8fbc2862"></a>
```

What does dat-key or data-send represent ? How do you use it? Is it a way to send data to the javascript file handling the request? Then how can you handle it in the javascript file?

Comment: unless you access it or use it, it does nothing. It's just a way of storing data in html in a way that doesn't invalidate your html while possibly being descriptive/expressive.

Answer (score 3):

They are HTML5 custom data attributes.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute

Answer (score 2):

**data-*** attributes are `HTML-5 custom attributes`

**Names** that are not `default attribute names` can be used by prepending the `data-` to make the `HTML` valid.

They can be retrieved by either using

```
$('.fb-like').attr('data-key')
```

**or**

```
$('.fb-like').data('key') // This is more appropriate
```

Comment: I don't think using a specialized javascript library here without mentioning it's name is appropriate. It has also nothing to do with the original HTML centric question.

Comment: What do you mean by `specialized javascript library ` ? It is just HTML I was referring to

Comment: `$` for sure is no HTML.

Comment: aahh.. I see.. you were referring to jQuery .. Op has tagged the question as jQuery .. So did not bother mentioning it

Comment: Thanks for that pointer - fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an attribute.  Instead of setting arbitrary attributes on an element, they added `data-*`.  They can contain whatever you want and have no inherit special meaning.

In jQuery, they can be accessed using `.data()`:

```
$('.fb-like').data('href')
```

Comment: Ohhh sweet!. So if it was set as data-key, using jquery I can access that value by doing $('.fb-like').data('key') ?

Comment: @MichaelNana: Yep :-)

Answer (score 1):

Data is the good way to add custom attributes to your HTML tags.

You can also acces them with the jquery function [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

```
$(element).data('key');//Will get the value of data-key
```

Answer (score 0):

data-* attributes is a way to attach some information to HTML element.

It doesn't do anything out of the box or affect behavior anyhow. However, it provides standards compliant way to assign some data to element.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get or set the values of data- attributes with jQuery. Examples are shown in the link below.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/